# left join and return only the latest record from right table using LARAVEL 6.5.0

Tags: php, sql, laravel, join, left-join

```
Table 1
----------
NameID     Name
------------------
1           A
2           B
3           C
-----------------

Table 2
--------------------
ID   NameID   Order   
--------------------
1      1      Sugar
2      1      Salt 
3      2      Garlic 
4      2      Sugar
5      2      Onion
6      3      Oil
7      3      Black pepper
```

> I want to return only the latest and only one record per nameID from
>   right table I dont know what code to use
>
> **This is the Result I want to return**

```
RESULT
----------------------------
Name           Order
---------------------------
A              Salt  
B              Onion    
C              Black pepper
```

> > Controller.php
>
> ```
> return DB::table('table1')
> ->leftjoin('table2','table1.nameID','=','table2.nameID')
> -get();
> ```

Comment: Are you trying to use the query builder or write your own raw query?

Comment: yes... See my post I edit it I put my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$data = Table1::select('Table1.Name', 'Table2.Order','Table2.ID')
->leftJoin('Table2', function($query) {
   $query->on('Table1.NameID','=','Table2.NameID')
        ->whereRaw('Table2.ID IN (select MAX(a2.ID) from Table2 as a2 join Table1 as u2 on u2.NameID = a2.NameID group by u2.NameID)');
})->get();
```

**Edited :**

```
$data = Table1::select('Table1.Name', 'Table2.Order','Table2.ID')
```

Comment: wow working but the ID of last data not displaying pls help me

Comment: not working even I try to use 'table1.* ',table2.*'

Answer (score 0):

Use not exists to filter

```
select Name, Order

from Table1 a 
inner join
(
Select a.NameID, Order from Table2 a 
where not exists(select 1 from Table2 b where a.NameID  = b.NameID  and a.ID < b.ID)
)b on a.NameID = b.NameID
```

Comment: I put this on my controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below script-

```
SELECT B.NameID, B.Name, C.[Order]
FROM 
(
    SELECT Nameid,MAX(ID) ID
    FROM table_2
    GROUP BY NameID
)A
INNER JOIN Table_1 B ON A.NameID = B.NameID
INNER JOIN Table_2 C ON A.NameID = C.NameID AND A.ID = C.ID
```